# Filter in the URL of a REST-API in Directus

Tags: rest, url, filter, directus

I know I can combine 2 filters in the URL using the `&` character for an `AND` operator (like in the code below), but how do I make an `OR` operator?

```
/items/bus_stops_bus_drivers?filter[bus_drivers_id][_eq]=2&filter[bus_stops_id][_eq]=3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/items/bus_stops_bus_drivers?filter={"_or":[{"bus_drivers_id":{"_eq": "2"}},{"bus_stops_id":{"_eq":"3"}}]}
```

Expanded filter version:

```json
"_or": [
    {
        "bus_drivers_id": {
            "_eq": "2"
        }
    },
    {
        "bus_stops_id": {
            "_eq": "3"
        }
    }
]
```

Visit the [official docs](https://docs.directus.io/reference/filter-rules.html#logical-operators) to read more about filtering rules and logical operators.